# How to search List of name which are present in cosmos documents

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a list of name. I need to find which name is present in FirstName or LastName Property of Document in Collection.

I had tried the Linq query to archive this but it through error ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.").

```
 public class UserDoc
{
   public string Id { get; set; }

   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string LastName { get; set; }

   public string DocumentType { get { return "userdoc"; } private set { } }
}

 List<string> Names = new List<string>() { "satya", "singh" };

 IEnumerable<UserDoc> Users = await _dBRepository.GetItemsAsync<UserDoc>
                (x => (Names.Contains(x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName))&& x.DocumentType == "userdoc");


public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
    {
        IDocumentQuery<T> query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollectionUri:
             UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId: _databaseId, collectionId: _collectionId),
            feedOptions: new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
             .Where(predicate)
             .AsDocumentQuery();

        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Mind telling us which line throws the exception?

Comment: Also I don't think that CosmosDB LINQ supports the `Contains` keyword.

Comment: @NickChapsas IDocumentQuery<T> query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T> .... line Throws the Exception.

Comment: @NickChapsas if CosmosDB LINQ does not Support Contains keyword then is there any way to Archive this?

Comment: Seems like we need to find out which property is null first because you are not getting a `NotSupportedException`. Can you debug and see which object is null in the `IDocumentQuery<T> query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery` line?

Comment: Ok I think I'm wrong because it supports the `in` keyword meaning `contains` will be translated to `in`. Still, find what is `null` there. Also based on the usage you are doing I think that [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) will be very handy for you.

Comment: according to your description, predicate seems a little but incorrect, try to do following: x => (Names.Contains(x.FirstName) || Names.Contains(x.LastName)) && x.DocumentType == "userdoc". This should help if null reference exception related to FirstName or LastName is null

Comment: btw, you'd better use do..while cycle intead of while..do cycle

Answer (score 0):

According to your description. You code should be modified as below:

```
IEnumerable<UserDoc> Users = await _dBRepository.GetItemsAsync<UserDoc>
            (x => (Names.Contains(x.FirstName)|| Names.Contains(x.LastName))&& x.DocumentType == "userdoc");
```

I have tested the code and it worked.

According to your error message, i think the the most likely reason is that the object `_client` point to Null, please check it and try again.